# Working with Microsoft.Web.Administration on a remote server in a different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I the following piece of code, and it works perfectly when it is run on a machine located in the same domain as the one in which is the remote server is.

However, if I run the same code on a machine which can reach the remote server, but is not in the same domain, then I get the following exception:

> UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine [***SERVER_HOSTNAME***] failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 [***SERVER_HOSTNAME***].

The exception is thrown by the call to `GetWebConfiguration`

It seems it's a question of my current credentials not being known on the remote server.

**Question**: How can I open a remote connection with custom credentials that are known remotely?

Code:

```
var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName);

Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration(locationPath);
ConfigurationSection accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access");
```

Comment: There is no such API. You will have to set up domain trust and let that remote machine accepts your credentials.

Comment: it is technically possible to do it, that's for sure, since it is possible to use the IIS manager to edit the settings of a machine located on another domain, provided valid credentials are used to connect.

Comment: MWA does not expose all underlying API. If you would like to wrap over the native API, you can find the docs in Microsoft open standard site.